# Calling the default constructor on c structs

Tags: c++, struct, extern

The code below compiles just fine (unless the call to `method` is uncommented).

1. Why is it allowed to "call" to the default constructor? (there shouldn't be one)
2. Why is the declaration of the member function not an error?

.

```
extern "C"
{
    struct S
    {
        int some_int;
        void method(){}
    };
}

int main()
{
    S s();
//    s.method();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `S s();` declares a fucntion, not an object.

Comment: What makes you thing there shouldn't be a default constructor?

Comment: Using `extern "C"` doesn't change *anything* except for disabling function-name mangling. See: [What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/10871073).

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: [Implicitly-declared default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `S s();` declares a function named `s` that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `S`. Just like `int f();`.

Second, that `extern "C"` isn't relevant here. It's used, roughly, for functions that are written in C and called from C++. It doesn't mean "pretend that this code is C code".

Third, `S` **does** have a default constructor. The compiler generates one. In this case it doesn't do anything, because there are no members of `S` that require non-trivial initialization. To use the default constructor you'd write `S s;` or `S s{};`.

Fourth, the reason that declaring a member function is okay is that a `struct` and a `class` in C++ can have member functions. I know, that sounds tautologous, but it's important to keep in mind that a `struct` can have member functions, static data, `private`, `protected`, and `public` members just like a `class`. The only differences between a `struct` and a `class` is that by default members of a class are private while members of a struct are public, and by default a base of a class is inherited privately while a base of a struct is inherited publicly.

Comment: `-Wvexing-parse` or just `-Wall` flag can catch the accidental function declarations with clang.

Comment: @Waqar -- this is **not** the ["most vexing parse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). I sure hope that some busybody compiler won't insist on telling me that `S s();` might be a mistake. That would make function declarations useless.

Comment: For the code provided by OP, [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/T3WsWE) does give that warning. But only for the things inside a function scope not in a global or namespace scope.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a default constructor (although it's optional here) and using curly-braces rather than parenthesis or you don't even need to use that, will solve your issue:

```
....
struct S {
    S() {} // declaring the constructor explicitly here
};
....

int main(void) {
    S s{}; // Don't use s() - a function, instead, call the
           // default constructor
//  S s;
    s.method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why add a default constructor?  The compiler provides one for free.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's because perhaps the OP wanted to use the constructor by `()`. So, I declared it explicitly.

Comment: But adding one doesn't let you use `()` so there's no reason to add it.

Comment: @NathanOliver OK, I've added the comment in line no. 3.

Comment: Re: "wants to use the constructor" -- sure, and `S s;` would use the default constructor, regardless of whether there's an explicit default constructor or a compiler-generated one.